# GCC Make Installation for Newbies

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, makefile, gnu-make

I'm getting more and more of a need for `make` (getting "deeper" into C++/C), so I downloaded it from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Then, I looked into the folder and started to do the install directions. I successfully started up `configure`, and got this:

```
loading cache ./config.cache
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
configure: error: no acceptable cc found in $PATH
```

So I interpreted that to mean that I needed GCC (or some other "cc"...?). So I went and downloaded *it* from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/). I ran its `configure`, and got this slightly longer (but still failed) result:

```
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/calebplace/Downloads/gcc-4.8.2':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Which means I need a C compiler (is this what a "cc" is?) before I can install it?

Basically, not being exactly a whiz at command-line usage or low-level computer languages (litotes alert), I was wondering...

**Can anyone explain how to install `make`?**

Comment: On what system?  Can't you just get binaries?  C compilers are usually written in C (or C++).

Comment: Using Mac. Not sure what you mean about *C compilers are usually written in C*...

Comment: So just download Xcode and you'll have a compiler.  By "C compilers are usually written in C" I mean just that - you'll need a C compiler to build one.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it :)

Comment: Just a point, there's really no such thing as "GCC building for newbies".  Building GCC is a complex (and time-intensive) operation; you'll need other packages (binutils, various libraries), worry about installation locations etc.  Compiling make is very simple (comparatively) but you do need a C compiler to build make.  It can be any compiler, so as others have mentioned you should get the one Apple provides, inside xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either download a pre-built binary or you can build it yourself.  However, if you are going to build it yourself, you need a C compiler (and probably `make` too) in order to do the compilation — a chicken and egg situation.

So, on Mac, you will probably need to get hold of XCode from Apple, and then install the XCode command line tools too.

Or you will need to go to one of the third-party sites ([Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) is one; there's another whose name eludes me right now) and get GCC etc from there.

With XCode installed, I was able to build GCC 4.8.1 fairly straight-forwardly on Mac OS X 10.8.5 (but I had problems with 4.8.0 when it was first released).  You do need to download enough prerequisites, though.

Comment: I've got the XCode app, and I'm supposing the "XCode command line tools" are the command-line version? Or something else?

Comment: You mean use XCode for the compiler?

Comment: Having XCode is a good start. There is a separate download called 'XCode Command Line Tools' or something very similar which is what luddites like me use the whole time.  This installs Git and SVN and make and cc and ... in `/usr/bin` ready for use.  The command line tools then use `clang` or `gcc` as the compiler (which you can then use to build almost anything else -- including GCC).